# Angular, when custom component has more than one input, then parent component ngModel will map to which child custom component control

Tags: angular

custom-input-test.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-input-test',
  templateUrl: './custom-input-test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom-input-test.component.css']
})
export class CustomInputTestComponent implements OnInit {
  external : string;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

custom-input-test.component.html

```
<p>
    input:
    </p>
    
      <app-custom-input [(ngModel)]="external" name="externalVal" ></app-custom-input>
      external: {{external}}
```

custom-input.component.ts

```
import { Component, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-input',
  template: `<input [(ngModel)]="test"/>Test:{{test}}
  <br/> 
  <input [(ngModel)]="value"/>local: {{val}}
  <br/>
  `,
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomInputComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class CustomInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

  constructor() { }

  onChange: any = () => {}
  onTouch: any = () => {}
  val= ""
  //value = "";
  
  set value(val){
    console.log("setter");
    if( val !== undefined && this.val !== val){
    this.val = val
    this.onChange(val)
    this.onTouch(val)
    }
   
  }
  

  writeValue(value: any){
    this.value = value
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any){
    this.onChange = fn
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any){
    this.onTouch = fn
  }

}
```

The question is:
in custom-input-test-component.html
`<app-custom-input [(ngModel)]="external" name="externalVal" ></app-custom-input>`
app-custom-input has two input (test input box and local input box), so in above statement, which textbox is linked to CustomInputTestComponent property external?
when run the application, I found only the local textbox will change CustomInputTestComponent.external, test textbox will not, but why?

*** Edit on 20230817 ***
if I change a bit on custom-input.component.ts as follow

```
  template: `<input [(ngModel)]="test"/>Test:{{test1}}
  <br/> 
  <input [(ngModel)]="value"/>local: {{val}}
  <br/>
  `,
```

and add a property

```
 test1=""
```

and add a setter function

```
set test(abc){
    console.log("test setter");
    if( abc !== undefined && this.test1 !== abc){
    this.test1 = abc
    this.onChange(abc)
    this.onTouch(abc)
    }
   
  }
```

then input of test textbox will change the CustomInputTestComponent external property also now, but the whole concept is still not very clear.

Answer (score 1):

You have:

1. writeValue(value:any) executed when change the variable in parent
2. this.onChange(val)    you force change the variable of the parent
3. In registerOnChange and registerOnTouched you say what variables you
   want to use, the function onChange could be called, e.g.
   myFabulousChange (are function that are defined in ControlValueAccessor that you need "override")

Comment: in
registerOnChange(fn: any){
    this.onChange = fn
  }, what is the function in fn:any and where is it passed from?

Answer (score 0):

after a long time web searching, I think the logic is

```
<app-custom-input [(ngModel)]="external" name="externalVal" ></app-custom-input>
```

when CustomInputTestComponent external property is changed programmatically, it will trigger ControlValueAccessor writeValue(value: any){...}, and we can assign the input parameter 'value' to any property of CustomInputComponent.
In this example, it change this.value property

```
writeValue(value: any){
    this.value = value
  }
```

which in turn trigger the setter function

```
set value(val){
```

and so modify this.val, and display in {{val}}
As inside writeValue(value:any), we have not changed test property, so {{test}} is not changed by CustomInputTestComponent external property.

And for

```
 template: `<input [(ngModel)]="test"/>Test:{{test}}
  <br/> 
  <input [(ngModel)]="value"/>local: {{val}}
  <br/>
```

when test or value is changed, we can call the function registered in

```
registerOnChange(fn: any)
```

which is this.onChange, and using this.onChange to modify outside parent CustomInputTestComponent external property.

but what is the fn: any inside registerOnChange is still unknown.